# Merging rows in R

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

I want to merge 2 data frames with matching columns and a common factor, but with different values in the rows, like this:

```
x <- data.frame(x = c("Uno", "Due", "Tre", "Quattro", "Cinque"), y = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
           x   y
     1     Uno A
     2     Due B
     3     Tre C
     4 Quattro D
     5  Cinque E

y <- data.frame(x = c("Uno", "Tre", "Cinque"), y = c("F", "G", "H")) 
           x   y
     1     Uno F
     2     Tre G
     3  Cinque H
```

and I want to get:

```
       x   y
 1     Uno A, F
 2     Due    B
 3     Tre C, G
 4 Quattro    D
 5  Cinque E, H
```

A lot of posts solve this with aggregate and merge for numbers, and I don't know what to do for strings. Do I have to make my own function, with function(x, etc)?

Comment: Is this always a left join? Or there could be values that aren't present in the `x` data frame? Also, are these values are `factor` or `character` class in real example?

Comment: Hi David, it's not only a left join, X might have data that is not present in Y and viceversa. The joining column could be a factor, but all the other columns are strings.

Answer (score 3):

If your values in the `y` column are characters rather factors, this could be an easy task using `data.table`

```
x <- data.frame(x = c("Uno", "Due", "Tre", "Quattro", "Cinque"), 
                y = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y <- data.frame(x = c("Uno", "Tre", "Cinque"), 
                y = c("F", "G", "H"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

(Notice the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`)

Then (assuming you always doing a left join)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[y, y := toString(c(y, i.y)), on = "x", by = .EACHI]
x
#          x    y
# 1:     Uno A, F
# 2:     Due    B
# 3:     Tre C, G
# 4: Quattro    D
# 5:  Cinque E, H
```

This is basically combining `y` columns from both data sets on the fly (while joining on the `x` columns) and updates `y` in place (without creating a new data set).

Comment: What if it's not always a left join? x might have entries that y doesn't have and viceversa.

Comment: Also, I made the mistake of calling the column like the files, and I am not sure which ones is which.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using `dplyr`

```
x <- data.frame(x = c("Uno", "Due", "Tre", "Quattro", "Cinque"), y = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), stringsAsFactors = F)

y <- data.frame(x = c("Uno", "Tre", "Cinque"), y = c("F", "G", "H"), stringsAsFactors = F) 


jdf <- full_join(x,y,"x") 

transmute(jdf, x = x, y = ifelse(is.na(y.y),y.x,paste(y.x, y.y, sep=', ')))

 x    y
1     Uno A, F
2     Due    B
3     Tre C, G
4 Quattro    D
5  Cinque E, H
```

Comment: I think you haven't mentioned all the packages used. Also, probably add the result of that operation

Comment: 1) `join_all` is not a dplyr function. 2) the output creates NA string combinations http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/join_all

Comment: Thanks for the input. I converted it to a pure dplyr answer. I had to borrow from @David Arenburg modification to use stringsASFactors.

Comment: I cannot find the join_all function in my plyr package, any idea why? thanks!